# Terraform-Datadog: Locate index inside a map element

Tags: terraform, datadog

I have created an monitors and slo resources that iterate through a map and creates several similar objects.
Now I am trying to create a dashboard and would like to pin point to the specific map index to find the slo resource. Example:

I have the bellow map:

```
example_map = {
    example_key0 = "example_value0"
    example_key1 = "example_value1"
    example_key2 = "example_value2"
}
```

I created the bellow slo's(monitors created in similar way):

```
resource "datadog_service_level_objective" "example_SLO" {
  count = length(var.example_map)
  name               = "example_slo_${keys(var.example_map)[count.index]}"
  type               = "monitor"
  description        = "${keys(var.example_map)[count.index]} metric SLO"
  monitor_ids        = ["${datadog_monitor.example_monitor[count.index].id}"]
  thresholds {
    timeframe = "90d"
    target = 99
    warning = 99.9
  }
  tags = ["type:slo_alerts"]
}
```

Each of these resources is then identified by the index(example_SLO[0], example_SLO[1],etc..)
On the dashboard i would like to pin point to the example key to get it's index. The bellow fails but I hope this example explains what i am to achieve:

```
widget {
      service_level_objective_definition {
        title = "example SLO"
        view_type = "detail"
        slo_id = datadog_service_level_objective.example_SLO[${index(keys(var.example_map), example_key2)}].id
        show_error_budget = true
        view_mode = "overall"
        time_windows = [
          "7d",
          "30d",
          "previous_month"]
      }
    }
```

Else is it possible to create a `for_each` or `count` argument for a widget? Create several objects from the same widget.

Thank you very much in advance for any help as this has become a roadblock in my attempt to reduce the configurations through map iteration. Which brings several levels of complexity.

Answer (score 0):

In Terraform maps are unordered, meaning they do not have an index. While, it is certainly possible to extract a list with the keys and get an index from there, this somewhat defies the purpose of having maps.

Since you have a map of strings, you can iterate through it using `for_each`:

```
resource "datadog_service_level_objective" "example_SLO" {
  for_each           = var.example_map
  name               = "example_slo_${each.key}"
  type               = "monitor"
  description        = "${each.key} metric SLO"
  monitor_ids        = [datadog_monitor.example_monitor[each.key].id]
  thresholds {
    timeframe = "90d"
    target = 99
    warning = 99.9
  }
  tags = ["type:slo_alerts"]
}
```

Please note, you have to use a similar `for_each` for your `datadog_monitor.example_monitor` resource as well.

For the `widget`, you probably could use [dynamic blocs](https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks), which will allow to have a `for_each` argument.

```
dynamic "widget" {
    for_each = var.example_map
    content {
      service_level_objective_definition {
        title             = "example SLO"
        view_type         = "detail"
        slo_id            = datadog_service_level_objective.example_SLO[each.key].id
        show_error_budget = true
        view_mode         = "overall"
        time_windows = [
          "7d",
          "30d",
        "previous_month"]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and answer. Seems dynamic widgets do not work for this case. Would there be some way to identify the position of an element inside a map?